# Upsert unique index Mongodb?

Tags: nosql, mongodb-4.0

I've written **ETL** in **MongoDB** which processes data from multiple collections and insert the processed data in new collection. While inserting processed data to new collection, I get **Duplicate key Error E11000** due to reprocessing of some already existing records and **_id** conflicts with existing. How can I upsert these duplicate documents??

I'm using this:

```
var data = db.getCollection("col1").find().toArray()
db.ProcessedData.insert(data,{upsert : true})
```

But no use.
I don't want to loop through all the records in col1 to insert one by one as it has large number of docs every run.

Comment: Please refer to the answer to almost the same exact question located at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974216/is-there-an-upsert-option-in-the-mongodb-insert-command